# Override docker not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I change ports in file 'docker-compose.override.yml' and run docker (docker-compose up). Docker isn't seeing my changes (ports) in override.

Content override:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - 87:80
```

Why docker isn't changing the port?

Comment: Please update your question to include: the contents of both docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml, `ls -l` output in the directory, `docker-compose version` output, and `docker-compose --verbose up` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your description of the problem is quite small and pure.
Actually, there are two ways of achieving thing you probably want to achieve.

So, by the first you can have several `docker-compose.yml` files.

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up -d`

On the other hand, you can use `extends` option.

Rememeber, that some options in `docker-compose.yml` can be concatanated, as the following quote says.

> For the multi-value options ports, expose, external_links, dns,
>   dns_search, and tmpfs, Compose concatenates both sets of values:

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: docker-compose.yml with an optional docker-compose.override.yml are the default files, you don't need to specify them. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files

Comment: This answer seems like it should **not** be required, based on [current docs for Multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files), which say: _"By default, Compose reads two files, a `docker-compose.yml` and an optional `docker-compose.override.yml` file."_

Comment: This worked for me! The problem was that I don't have these files in root (`/`), but in `/deployment/`, and I was running the command from root. Hence `docker-compose -f deployment/docker-compose.yml -f deployment/docker-compose.override.yml up`.

Answer (score 0):

The filename 'docker-composer.override.yml' is incorrect, you need to use 'docker-compose.override.yml'.